# How do I get the expand properties when using JIRA ''Get IDs of updated worklogs'' REST api?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Using JIRA, I get a list of IDs for worklogs updated by using [this api](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/#api-api-2-worklog-updated-get).

`/rest/api/2/worklog/updated`

I can get the regular request to work, but there is a parameter called `expand` to display additional properties of the worklog and I can not get these properties to appear.

Things I have tried so far.

`/rest/api/2/worklog/updated?expand=spentTime`

`/rest/api/2/worklog/updated?expand=authorName,comment`

The example response in JIRA document (link mentioned above) has a field called `properties`. It may be used to contain expand properties.

[image: JIRA response]

But I don't know why my response doesn't have that field.

[image: My response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're looking for is `timeSpent`, expanding `properties` is not the correct approach. You're going to get the relevant `workLogIds` returned by [Get IDs of updated worklogs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/#api-api-2-worklog-updated-get), then make a second REST call to [Get worklogs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/#api-api-2-worklog-list-post). This call will give you `timeSpent`, and `updateAuthor` among others. However, it will not give you comments; you'll be needing a different call for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's exactly the way I am thinking of. I just want to know whether I could do it shorter or not with this `expand` property. So I think I should have it done with your approach. Thank you.